# setInterval com auto-clearInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou criando uma forma de extrair dados do Twitter sem que seja cotado com os valores da API deles. A melhor forma que encontrei foi usando o widget que eles disponibilizam (e que não tem cota) e a partir de seu carregamento eu "pegar as informações" e tratá-las.

O meu problema é que não estou conseguindo pensar numa forma de fazer a página verificar se existe uma tag no elemento `body` que o Twitter cria após seu carregamento `[data-twttr-rendered=true]`.

Tentei fazer um `setInterval` analisando se isso existe e, caso exista ele executa uma função e como *callback* já executa seu próprio `clearInterval` assim:

```
var twitter = setInterval(function(){
    if($('body[data-twttr-rendered=true]').length != 0){
        page.twitter.mutage(function(){clearInterval(twitter)});
    }
},1000);
```

O problema que ao executar tal código eu consigo bugar o DOM e travo o site inteiro...
Alguém ai tem uma resposta melhor pra mim por favor?

Comment: Pra que serve a função `page.twitter.mutage`? E pra que cancelar o intervalo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O motivo do site "travar" é porque provavelmente está gerando inúmeras chamadas do `setInterval`.

O `setInterval` nunca para a não ser quando chamado o `clearInterval`, diferente do `setTimeout` que para após o processo.

No seu código provavelmente está executando várias vezes está parte:

```
var twitter = setInterval(function(){
...
},1000);
```

Ou seja ficam vários "eventos" rodando ao mesmo tempo e provavelmente ficam sendo criados novos, até o navegador não aguentar.

Você pode fazer duas coisas:

1. Usar `setTimeout` ao invés de `setInterval`, pois o primeiro espera o evento terminar diferente do `setInterval`.
2. Criar um verificação se o seu código já está rodando, isto você pode usar a própria váriavel `twitter`

O código deve ficar algo como:

```
var exec;
var twitter = null;
var initiate = function () {
    if (twitter === null) {//Se a variavel for null então executa, se não previne executar mais de uma vez
        var exec = function () {
            if($('body[data-twttr-rendered=true]').length !== 0){
                page.twitter.mutage(function(){
                    //...Código pode ser chamado, não necessita de window.clearTimeout
                });
            } else {
                //Se não encontrar o atributo data-twttr-rendered=true em body então executa novamente
                twitter = window.setTimeout(exec, 1000);
            }
        };
        exec();
    }
};
initiate();//Inicia o event
```

### MutationObserver

Outra metodo que você pode usar é o [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), porém como você está usando jQuery, então irei lhe indicar um plugin que faz um trabalho parecido, é o [jQuery-Observer](https://github.com/kapetan/jquery-observe).

```
var bodyDetect = $('body');
bodyDetect.observe({
    "attributes": true,
    "attributeFilter": ['data-twttr-rendered']
}, function(record) {
    page.twitter.mutage(function () {
        //...Código pode ser chamado
    });
});
```

Comment: @LeandroLUK Havia um erro no código com `setTimeout` eu corrigi, se estiver usando ele por favor atualize